# Calculating image and kernel of a projection

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, analytic-geometry

I need help with part b in this problem:

Let $V$ be a vector space and $π$ an endomorphism of $V$.

a. Prove that $π$ is a projection if and only if $id_V − π$ is a projection, where
$id_V$ is the identity endomorphism on $V$.

b. Assume now that $π$ is a projection. Calculate $Im(id_V −π)$ and $ker(id_V −π)$
as a function of $Im(π)$ and $ker(π)$.

---

I am familiar with identity automorphism but what does identity endomorphism mean and what is it's transformation matrix?

I assumed it's $I$ (the identity matrix) so I used the condition for a projection:
$(I-P)^2=I-P$

Where $P$ is transformation matrix for $π$, and from this we obtain:

$P^2=P$

So π is indeed a projection, but now for part b I know that $Im(π)=span(P_i)$ (span of columns of P) and I don't know how to continue from here...

Comment: Call $L$ the subspacd base of the projection (this is, $\pi = id$ for those $x$ in $L$ and the null endomorphism for those $x$ not in $L$). $L$ is the image of the projection.Then clearly the image of $id-\pi$ is $L^c = ker(\pi)$ and the kernel of $id-\pi$ is $L$

Comment: There are three definitions to keep in mind. Let $V,W$ be vector spaces. A vector space homomorphism from $V$ to $W$ is a linear transformation $T\colon V\to W$. A vector space endomorphism on $V$ is just a linear transformation $T\colon V\to V$. A vector space automorphism on $V$ is just a linear transformation $T\colon V\to V$ that is a bijection. The identity map on $V$ is simultaneously a homomorphism from $V\to V$, an endomorphism on $V$, and an automorphism due to bijectivity. There is always only one identity map on any set.